# how to avoid huge memory allocation when sending numpy array to vbo?

Tags: python, opengl, pyopengl

When I sent a big numpy array to the vbo, the memory goes up, up to a gig.

The shape of the array is (120000, 1), each vertex is x,y,z,r,g,b.
The array can be bigger but whatever its size the allocation is disproportionate.

I added `OpenGL.ERROR_ON_COPY = True` but it doesn't trigger.

I use the vbo module from `OpenGL.arrays`
the vbo line is `self.vbo = vbo.VBO( vertices, usage=buffer.usage)` . Nothing special AFAICT.

The only lead I have, is that I build and delete many vao/vbos as the mesh is filled and they are kept in memory (even if one uses `VBO.delete()`, which I do ).

Either I am doing something wrong or I hit a buggy use case.

Any idea on how to solve this ?

Comment: It may the absence of an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that makes your question less appealing for potential answerers.

Comment: Without a [mcve] this a game of trial and error

Comment: working on it but it takes a bit of time.

Comment: May you please provide a minimal working code example ?